False conditionals and using different conjunctions
1 If you know her, why don't you ask her?
In English we have so called false conditionals. My first example is a good instance of that. "If" doesn't really estsblish condition there. It rather means "since you know her". We have other words that establish condition like "provided or as long as or supposing". Could we use them too in false conditionals?

Provided/supposing/as long as you know her, why don't you ak her?


Didn't you understand what people told you in answer to your previous question? It makes absolutely no sense to use provided etc. in this context.

@KateBunting why? Is it too formal?

What about formal situation? "Provided you now the current state of affairs you can take legal actions"

Why? Because, as you said yourself, in this case if means since you know her. It's regarded as a fact that 'you' do know her - that's why it's a false conditional.  The level of formality is irrelevant.

Offhand I can't think of any other word apart from if that can be used both to introduce a possibility (if condition is true) AND to point out a relevant fact (since condition is true, as condition is true, given [that] condition is true) One that comes close is assuming [that] condition is true... But I guess it's worth pointing out that if in the OP's cited context is effectively equivalent to something like IF we accept the apparently incontestable truth of the assertion that... In this context, provided isn't really a useful term on its own

See How does the false-conditional work in "I made sandwiches if you want some"? as asked on our sister site English Language and Usage

That 1) is not a false conditional.

Can "provided you know her" have the meaning "since you know her", i.e. "seeing as you know her" ?
No.
Ditto, "supposing you know her"?
No.
Ditto, "as long as you know her"?
Yes.

As long as you're in town, why not drop in on your cousin? He'd be sad to think you were here and didn't take time to say hello.
As long as you're here, you might as well take a look at this Picasso sketch on a napkin we picked up recently at auction.


Anonymous downvoter, explain what you think is wrong with the answer.
